# Printing pointer value with increment of the address in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int k,*ptr=NULL;
int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
ptr=arr;
printf("%d ",*ptr++);
printf("%d ",*(ptr++));
printf("%d ",(*ptr)++);
printf("%d ",*++ptr);
printf("%d ",++*ptr);
}
```

Why does the second `printf` print the number `2` ? It should print `3`.

Comment: Why should it print 3 exactly?

Comment: You're doing post-increment instead of pre-increment. That's why it's a good idea to increment separately from doing whatever you want to do with the incremented variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone else said, the distinction is between pre-incrementing (where the increment occurs before the value is fetched) and post-incrementing (where the value is fetched and then the increment occurs).  The value 2 should be printed, of course.

Maybe this assertion-laden code will help.  The `assert()` macro stops the program if the condition specified is false when it is executed.  The assertions do not fire.

The assertions show how the value of `ptr` changes, and also how the values in the array change.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int *ptr = arr;

    assert(ptr == &arr[0]);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr++);      // print 1; ptr = &arr[1]
    assert(ptr == &arr[1]);
    printf("%d\n",*(ptr++));    // print 2; ptr = &arr[2]
    assert(ptr == &arr[2]);
    assert(*ptr == 3);
    printf("%d\n",(*ptr)++);    // print 3; ptr = &arr[2]; arr[2] = 4
    assert(ptr == &arr[2]);
    assert(*ptr == 4);
    printf("%d\n",*++ptr);      // print 4; ptr = &arr[3]
    assert(ptr == &arr[3]);
    assert(*ptr == 4);
    printf("%d\n",++*ptr);      // print 5; ptr = &arr[3]; arr[3] = 5
    assert(ptr == &arr[3]);
    assert(*ptr == 5);

    printf("Offset: %d\n", (int)(ptr - arr));
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
Offset: 3
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 4
a[3] = 5
a[4] = 5
a[5] = 6
a[6] = 7
a[7] = 8
a[8] = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

post increment operator increments the variabl **after** accessing the value.

So, **after** getting `*ptr`, which is 2, `ptr` increases itself.

Comment: ah ! so its the same as "*ptr++" right? the ( ) is there just to trick us right?

Comment: @YuHao No, the precedence of the postfix `++` is higher than that of the indirection operator `*`. `*ptr++` and `*(ptr++)` are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Not, because ptr++ return the value BEFORE the incrementation, so the value is 2.

Comment: ah ! so its the same as "*ptr++" right?
the  (  ) is there just to trick us right?

Comment: In this case yes.
*(ptr++) -> increment ptr and return a pointer on a "2", so printf display 2.

Answer (score 0):

*ptr++ first dereferences the pointer which gives 2, then increments the pointer
The expression *(ptr++) is a post increment expression so the value of of that expression is ptr and then it is incremented. So the result of the expression is that it still points to the 2

Answer (score 0):

the * operator applies to the result of p++, which is the value of original p (prior to the increment). So it prints `2`. I you want `3` to be printed you should do (++p) which returns the incremented value.

Answer (score 0):

The `*ptr++` returns the value at `ptr` and then increments it,so in the second `printf()` statement it only returns 2 and then increments it to 3.

Answer (score 0):

It should print 2, because the postfix operator ++ first returns the value and then increments it.
The fact that you added brackets around it (*(ptr++)) does not influence the increment.
The value will be incremented after the whole line.

Looking at disassembly might help you to see what happens at that line.